# How to not get hard edges in Eevee transparent emission material?

Tags: shaders, eevee-render-engine

[image]

I have an emission for a jet flame for a 4 sided pyramid but it just looks solid or like glass.  How can I remove the IOR value and have an emitting transparent shader for a jet flame?

If this is not possible in Eevee, how could I do it, softening the edges etc?

Comment: One idea is that if you decrease the emission strength and decrease the bloom until they match, you shouldn't be able to see the switch from object to bloom.

Comment: I am trying to keep the light for illumination also, so that won't help much, but will try also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to mix the final shader with a transparent shader and use fresnel node as factor(fac) value, then you can use fresnel's ior value or a color ramp for controlling smoothness and area to be cut.(Switch color ramp to B-spline for smoothest transition you can have.)

Comment: I did that and it worked, but b-spline was too bright in that setup.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try use alpha mask to make some parts transparent . Or decrease pyramid size and increase emission to match original. There are probably better solutions tho